# folders created by mkdir() are not accessible

Tags: php

I'm using `mkdir()` inside a foreach loop to create my folders:

```
if (!file_exists($id))
{
    mkdir($id);
}
```

*`$id` could be `529e1f4070b0c`*

Folders are created but when accessing them by FTP or directly from Direct Admin file manager, I encounter **No such file or directory**, also a 404 Not found page when accessing through browser.

What's wrong?

***#Update 1***

I removed `foreach` loop and assigned `$id` manually that works well, folder created and is accessible, but when it's inside `foreach`, folders are created but not accessible!

***#Update 2***

I changed the code to use full path as recommended in comments:

```
if (!file_exists(dirname(__FILE__)."/".$id))
{
    mkdir(dirname(__FILE__)."/".$id, 0777);
}
```

Which also leads to previous results!

***#Update 3***

Complete code of block:

```
$file = file("codes.txt");
foreach ($file as $id)
{
    $html = content_of_url($id);
    if (!file_exists(dirname(__FILE__)."/".$id))
    {
        mkdir(dirname(__FILE__)."/".$id, 0777);
    }
    $dom = new domDocument;
    $dom->loadHTML($html);
    $dom->preserveWhiteSpace = false;
    $images = $dom->getElementsByTagName('img');
    foreach ($images as $i => $img)
    {
        $url = str_replace("../..", "http://domain.com", $img->getAttribute('src'));
        file_put_contents(dirname(__FILE__)."/".$id."/".$i.".jpg", file_get_contents($url));
    }
}
```

Comment: try to give full path

Comment: @VaheShadunts let me try.

Comment: @VaheShadunts didn't try full path yet but updated the post for an edit.

Comment: @VaheShadunts I did it. Please see the #2 update.

Comment: I've tried with foreach creating folders with foreach, it work good, no any problems

Answer (score 0):

Use the below

```
if (!is_dir($id))
{
    mkdir($id,0777);
}
```

Assume you are creating folder inside a 'ID FOLDER' folder

then specify the path too

```
if (!is_dir('ID FOLDER'.$id))
{
    mkdir('ID FOLDER'.$id,0777);
}
```

Comment: As said in php.net/mkdir, `The mode is 0777 by default` and I don't think that change in if, will affect the result made by `mkdir`

Comment: first clear where are you placing folders and how you are accessing them ?

Comment: I said in question how I access them. `php` file is in a folder so wanted folders placed there.

Answer (score 0):

try to set permissions :) and set recursive = true

```
$path = "folder/path/where/files/should/be/stored/";
mkdir($path , 0777, true);
```

DON'T give Filename with it... first create Path, than File

```
$handle = fopen( $path . "\ressource.txt", "r");
```

you may need to replace / with \\

Comment: `The mode is 0777 by default`

Comment: if i add a folder without permissions ill get 0644 as permission. may its because of the php security settings on my server. don't know. but u should check :)

Answer (score 0):

change the permission, this might help

Comment: I did but nothing changes.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use backslashes under Windows or use the constant DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR in the path. And also you can try to change the permission.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set permission on the folder to be accessed by "non apache" users.
Use the chmod instruction.
http://www.php.net/chmod

Comment: they are under my user and not apache

Answer (score 0):

After creating the folder try to change the folder permission with [`chmod()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.chmod.php).